# Where can I find all avaliable fields in editor.tokenColorCustomization setting for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to customize color scheme. I found a great theme, but in order to use it with JS it needs to be customized, especially objects highlighting.
Here is my settings.json:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Outrun Night]": {
        "strings": "#ffbb00"
    },
}
```

But I can't find any docs about which fields are allowed in tokenColorCustomization, so I don't know how to customize objects. Now they're just white